# How to get Mana to "Follow" in Dungeon Defenders?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I've seen some vids of people playing Dungeon Defenders, and all they have to do is run past mana and it will fly up and follow them and be collected.

How do you make this happen? (I'm sure sick of waiting for chests to disappear after opening...)

Edit: System info -- running DD from Humble Bundle on Xubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry guys, I obviously didn't look hard enough before posting the question:

It's a [specific bug in the Linux port](https://bugzilla.icculus.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5831) due to a lack of PhysX support in nVidia drivers.

Cheers for all the responses.

Comment: Old post, but I see that it is still a problem....if you play with a friend who is hosting the game on Windows, it works properly. So I do not believe them when they talk driver issues.

Comment: @Goose: That seems reasonable though, since the host will be modelling the motion physics in that case? No update from Ryan yet on a PhysX port :(

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to do anything, it happens automatically.  Unless your mana is full, in which case, spend the mana you have.

Comment: Not for me...I have to "run over" the bricks to collect them.

Comment: @ash I vaguely remember I had to do that in the beginning as well, but it happens automatically now. Maybe the range increases as you level?

Comment: @Ash "Mana crystals are attracted to any nearby hero who is carrying less than their maximum capacity. These crystals will move towards the hero but can be impeded by the terrain or other objects." From the [Dungeon Defenders wiki](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Mana)

Comment: @Kevin Thanks, I'm not sure what's wrong, whether it's a setting or something. I just reinstalled the latest update from HumbleBundle, so it should be fresh. But my guys don't attract mana at all...

Comment: @Ash There's some pretty distinct differences in the PC version as compared to the console/mobile versions, so much so that there were separate wikis for a while (I'm behind on the game so I can't confirm for sure anymore). This may be one of those differences.

Comment: Well, I have the Mac version and don't have any problems with attracting mana gems.